# What does the following parameter mean in C++ thread constructor?

Tags: c++

I'm reading a piece of code of a graph database and in the constructor I find the following code snippet:

```
CommitManager(std::string path, std::atomic<timestamp_t> &_global_epoch_id)
            : fd(EMPTY_FD),
              seq_front{0, 0},
              seq_rear{0, 0},
              mutex(),
              client_mutex(),
              cv_server(),
              cv_client(),
              global_client_mutex(0),
              used_size(0),
              file_size(0),
              global_epoch_id(_global_epoch_id),
              writing_epoch_id(global_epoch_id),
              unfinished_epoch_id(),
              queue(),
              closed(false),
              server_thread([&] { server_loop(); })
```

And later it has

```
void server_loop()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                check_unfinished_epoch_id();
                int local_client_mutex = global_client_mutex.load();
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex[local_client_mutex]);
                auto &local_queue = queue[local_client_mutex];
                while (local_queue.empty() && !closed.load())
                {
                    cv_server.wait_for(lock, SERVER_SPIN_INTERVAL, [&]() {
                        check_unfinished_epoch_id();
                        return !local_queue.empty() || closed.load();
                    });
                    check_unfinished_epoch_id();
                    cv_client[local_client_mutex ^ 1].notify_all();
                }
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> client_lock(client_mutex[local_client_mutex]);

                global_client_mutex ^= 1;

                size_t num_txns = local_queue.size();

                if (!num_txns)
                    break;

                ++writing_epoch_id;

                unfinished_epoch_id.emplace(writing_epoch_id, 0);

                auto &num_unfinished = unfinished_epoch_id.back().second;

                std::string group_wal;
                group_wal.append(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&writing_epoch_id), sizeof(writing_epoch_id));
                group_wal.append(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&num_txns), sizeof(num_txns));

                for (size_t i = 0; i < num_txns; i++)
                {
                    auto &[wal, ret_epoch_id, ret_num] = local_queue.front();

                    group_wal.append(wal);
                    *ret_epoch_id = writing_epoch_id;
                    *ret_num = &num_unfinished;
                    ++num_unfinished;
                    local_queue.pop();
                }

                auto expected_size = used_size + group_wal.size();
                if (expected_size > file_size)
                {
                    size_t new_file_size = (expected_size / FILE_TRUNC_SIZE + 1) * FILE_TRUNC_SIZE;
                    if (fd != EMPTY_FD)
                    {
                        if (ftruncate(fd, new_file_size) != 0)
                            throw std::runtime_error("ftruncate wal file error.");
                    }
                    file_size = new_file_size;
                }

                used_size += group_wal.size();

                if (fd != EMPTY_FD)
                {
                    if ((size_t)write(fd, group_wal.c_str(), group_wal.size()) != group_wal.size())
                        std::runtime_error("write wal file error.");
                }

                if (fd != EMPTY_FD)
                {
                    if (fdatasync(fd) != 0)
                        std::runtime_error("fdatasync wal file error.");
                }

                ++num_unfinished;

                lock.unlock();
                seq_front[local_client_mutex] += num_txns;
                cv_client[local_client_mutex].notify_all();
                client_lock.unlock();

                --num_unfinished;
            }
        }
private:
std::thread server_thread;
```

I'm particularly confused about `server_thread([&] { server_loop(); })` I assumed it was creating a thread to run the `server_loop()` function but I'm confused about the syntax of `[&]` and why it has to use "{}" to enclose the function. I recall in C's thread we pass the function and arguments as parameters when we create a new thread.

Comment: C++ syntax can be very hard to search for with a general-purpose web search engine. [A good language reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4581301) can make this easier.

Comment: I hope there are no virtual functions that could be overwritten by a subclass in use in `server_loop` and that `server_thread` is the last member variable in the type (at least the last one used by the thread. Otherwise you may easily end up with undefined behaviour. Furthermore it would be preferrable to capture `this` by value instead of just capturing everything by reference: `server_thread([this] { server_loop(); })`. Perhaps passing a member function pointer would be preferrable though: `server_thread(&CommitManager::server_loop, this)`

Comment: Hello, thanks so much. I was also more familiar with passing a function pointer as the argument. So I assume the ```[&]```, the lambda expression as others pointed out, captures the other things within the class?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). It captures everything from the outer scope by reference using `[&]` and takes no parameters. The code inside the braces is the body of the lambda.